# Path to add NTv2 transformation to QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, datum

Every time I start a new QGIS project, I have to add the BETA2007.gsb NTv2 Transformation. I would like to modify my QGIS settings in a way, that the NTv2 is automatically added to the project.

When I start a new QGIS Projekt, the following setting dissapears and I need to add the transformation again.

[image]

After I add the NTv2 manually via the QGIS UI, in which file is it added?

QGIS has to make a reference somewhere.

I'm using QGIS 3.4.13

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the file into:

`QGIS_BASE_FOLDER\share\proj`

QGIS uses proj for re-projection, any transformations in there should be automatically detected.

Edit:

Also to note, I am using QGIS 3.10 and BETA2007.gsb is already included. So upgrading might help as well.

Edit 2:

In answer to the updated question. You can set default transformations in Settings>Options>CRS>Default Datum Transformations

[image]

Comment: it is already included in 3.4 as well, but it was not exaclty what I was asking. I edited my question and added an image.